# PHP changing numbers to the strings with str_replace without mixed up

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace

I am changing numbers to the strings. Like that:

```
1=>A
2=>B
3=>C
4=>D
5=>E
6=>F
7=>G
8=>H
9=>I
10=>J
11=>K
12=>L
```

I made this function to be replace:

```
function name($string) {
    $find=array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
    $replace=array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L");
    $string=str_replace($find,$replace,$string);  
    return $string;
}
```

But if i use this: `name("12");` its not returning `L` its return `AB`.

Actually its make sense. Returning each letter. How can i return `L` in this function? What should i do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try and reverse the arrays: `array('12', '11', '10', ...)` and `array('L', 'K', ...)` .

Comment: why you're using `str_replace()` for this kind of requirement? simple `range()` or `chr()` functions are good approach

Comment: Wow thats brilliant. I have never thought of that. Thanks @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Letters is just an example. They are mostly paragraphs @don'tangryme

Comment: @AliÖzen wooops..then plz mention it on your question :)

Comment: I have a question based on the input to your function. Why 12 should be interpretted as 12 and not as '1'+'2'? How the system should distinguish between these two cases?

Comment: How should it behave when called with `"13"` or `"abc"` as value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str_replace()` with array replace provided string with any match in array items. So use `array_search()` like shown in bottom instead

```
$result = $replace[array_search($string, $find)];
```

So your code changed to

```
function name($string) {
    $find = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12");
    $replace = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L");  
    return $replace[array_search($string, $find)]; 
}
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/XEQUT)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `str_replace()` just replaces them in the order that you specify as stated in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)...

> **Replacement order gotcha**
>
> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing
>   multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.

If you instead use [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) it will replace them longest first...

```
$string=strtr($string, array_combine($find, $replace));
```

Answer (score 1):

You do have a PHP function for what you are trying to achieve - [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)

```
<?php 

function name($string) {
   return chr(intval($string) + 64);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

- Thanks to @Ulrich. You can better describe the above solution using `ord('A')`.  So, basically you add the ASCII value of `A` to the integer converted string parameter and subtract 1 from it, to get the ASCII value for the character we are seeking. `chr()` finally gives us that character.

```
function name($string) {
   return chr(intval($string) + ord('A') - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, idk that. But in my case letters can be words.

Comment: @AliÖzen But you never said that in your question.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. My mistake sir.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple mapping:

```
$mapping = [
    '1' => 'A',
    '2' => 'B',
    '12' => 'L',
];
if (!array_key_exists($string, $mapping)) {
    throw new Exception('invalid input provided');
}
return $mapping[$string];
```

Answer (score 0):

**If I don't understood your question then**, Try with `range()` instead of long **key=>value** array. I think for your current requirement `str_repalce()` is not a good choice, simple `range()` will do the magic :)

```
<?php
  function name($num){
    $array = range('A','Z');
    $array = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $array));
    return $array[$num];
  }

 echo name(12);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/kl9jn

Answer (score 0):

instead of `str_replace` use [**chr**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)

```
function name($string) {
    return chr( $string + 64 );
}
```

note that this will word as long a `$string` is actually containing a number in the range 1 .. 26

---

But if -for some reason- you want to stick with the `str_replace` approach a solution is to pad numbers with a leading and following space (or a character of your choice...), this way:

```
function name($string) {
    $string = " " . $string . " ";
    $find=array(" 1 "," 2 "," 3 "," 4 "," 5 "," 6 "," 7 "," 8 "," 9 "," 10 "," 11 "," 12 ");
    $replace=array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L");
    $string=str_replace($find,$replace,$string);  
    return $string;
}
```